# filter model with foreignKey

Tags: python, django

I have these 2 models:

```
class Canva(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    site = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)s
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

class Bilan(models.Model):
    agregat = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    SCF = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    canva = models.ForeignKey('Canva', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bilan_canva')
```

How can I filter the Bilan class by the "created" attribut in the Canva class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It should be something like this:**

```
Bilan.objects.filter(canva__created__gte/gt/lte/lt=date/datetime)
```

Here,

gte = greater or equal

gt = greater

lte = smaller or equal

lt = smaller

```
Bilan.objects.filter(canva__created__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with `canva__created`. For example if you want to retrieve all items created today, you can work with:

```
Bilan.objects.filter(canva__created__gte='2021-9-5')
```

here the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) thus retrieves `Bilan` objects where the `canva` has a `created` timestamp greater than or equal to `2021-9-5 00:00:00`.